# mvc - dropdownlist not populating correctly within Edit view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I'm building my first MVC application, having followed the 'NerdDinner' tutorial through. In creating a dropdownlist from a SelectList in the same way, however, I'm running into an issue.

For some reason, when I bring up the 'Edit' view, the dropdownlist isn't showing the correct selection, even though the data is set otherwise in the database and the 'Details' view shows the correct value. Every one is just coming up with the first value in the list.

I've been through the NerdDinner code piece by piece and can't for the life of me see any difference, yet that application will correctly show the dropdown with the current value when editing, and mine doesn't.

Anyone have a suggestion for where to go from here? I can post code snippets if someone asks for something specific.

**Update:**

Within a fieldset:

```
        <p>
            <label for="Parking">Parking Arrangement:</label>
            <%= Html.DropDownList("Parking", Model.Parking)%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Parking", "*") %>
        </p>
```

The Edit action:

```
    //
    // GET: /Buyer/Edit/2
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Buyer_Profile buyer_profile = buyerRepository.GetBuyerProfileByID(id);

        if (buyer_profile == null)
            return View("NotFound");
        else if (!buyer_profile.IsOwnedBy(User.Identity.Name, id))
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        else
            return View(new BuyerFormViewModel(buyer_profile));
    }
```

In the same way they construct it for the NerdDinner example, I created a '...FormViewModel':

```
public class BuyerFormViewModel
{
    // Properties
    public Buyer_Profile Buyer_Profile { get; private set; }
    public SelectList Parking { get; private set; }

    // Constructor
    public BuyerFormViewModel(Buyer_Profile buyer_profile)
    {
        Buyer_Profile = buyer_profile;
        Parking = new SelectList(BuyerProfileOptions.Parking, Buyer_Profile.Parking);
    }
}
```

And the generated HTML when clicking on 'edit' when a value is already shown in the details view and stored in the d/b:

```
<p>
  <label for="Parking">Parking Arrangement:</label>
  <select id="Parking" name="Parking"><option>No Preference</option>
  <option>On Street</option>
  <option>Assigned Street</option>
  <option>Open Garage</option>
  <option>Covered Garage</option>
  </select>                
</p>
```

The text fields in the same form have their values populated correctly. It's just all the dropdowns which don't!

Many thanks for your attention.

Comment: I've been through with the debugger step-by-step and by the time it finishes rendering the page the right things looks like it's going to come out. But...it just doesn't.

Comment: Can you post the snippet of the HtmlHelper and of the Edit action.

And the HTML output too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh. It appear that htmlhelper is TOO good. I removed the references to the model and everything works!

i.e.

```
 <%= Html.DropDownList("Parking", Model.Parking)%>
```

becomes

```
 <%= Html.DropDownList("Parking")%>
```

and we're golden. Is it that ViewData contains something called 'Parking' because I'm referencing it in the model so it squashes the other value...or something...?

Comment: The second parameter for the drop down list is the selected value, you have probably strongly typed your view so that the model is your view model, therefore by doing Model.Parking the Parking property is actually your selectlist object.. where as if you do model.Buyer_Profile.Parking  that might also work.

Answer (score 2):

Quick tip for people - don't name any of your model properties 'Title' when they need a dropdown list. The framework will get mixed up with the View Title and won't work - I spent a full afternoon tearing my hair out over this. Needed to sleep on it to realise what was going on.